# Where are the visual C++ redistributable packages installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

So I'm trying to install microsoft visual studio 2015 community on my windows 8 pc but the installer keeps stopping and claiming that the 2013 redistributable cannot be found. I know it is installed. One of the options is to specify a file path to the redistributable. So I'm wondering where it is exactly I can find these files on my computer? Thanks for any help.

Comment: IIRC. VS 2013 usually put them in the system32.

Comment: Okay ill check there to see

Comment: do you know if there is another folder under system32 it would be in?

Comment: No, they should be in the path. That's probably why it is complaining about them not being installed.

Comment: Hmm okay well i reinstalled the packages and tried redirecting visual studio to them and it said it couldn't find them there. Not sure what's going on. Stupid Microsoft.

Comment: Could be a corrupt installer, maybe just check the checksums. It sounds like a very odd error

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help Niall. I'll figure it our eventually.

Comment: In "Add/Remove Programs" or "Programs and Features," is there an entry for "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86)"? If so, what version is installed? Is the 64-bit redistributable installed? Are msvcr120.dll and msvcp120.dll present in the system directories (C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64)? What is the exact error reported by Visual Studio 2015 Setup? At what point does installation fail?

Comment: I hope your still around to answer this but I have both the x86 and x64 versions installed. Both msvcr120 and msvcp120 dll's are installed. The error "A setup package is either missing or damaged" occurs right near the begging of the setup when trying to install visual C++ 2013

Comment: Also, I had it installed previously with everything working correctly until I did a microsoft update and I couldn't even open a project or start a new one without some error claiming some object didn't exist. I uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio with the updates still intact and this error is now occurring. Could it be that microsoft maybe placed the 2013 redistributables in a different folder with the update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those of you who are having this same issue I ended up getting the answer. As of right now, Sept. 9th 2015, the official answer from Microsoft support is:

"The problem is related to the use of Visual Studio web-installer. It will download C++ package from website, but the link of C++ package seems broken.

The temporary solution is to download the full ISO format and use it to install. You can download the ISO from official site and verify the checksum:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-iso-sha1-vs.aspx"

So there you have it. Download the ISO version of the program which can also be found on the main download page for visual studio.

Comment: Very interesting, well done in getting that figured out.

Comment: Do you know where exactly those DLLs get installed with the redistributable installers? I can't force users to download the redistributable from Microsoft. I must provide all the DLLs and send them to the right places with an installer. This requires extracting the dlls after installing the redistributable myself. Unfortunately, the whole process is a black box and a thorough searching of the C drives reveals about 100 vcruntimeXXX.dll carried by every single app that depends on it. By just adding a random one my app crashes, possibly due to the path and configuration nuances in those dlls.